# Do you split a straight

Tags: texas-hold-em, straight

If the board is showing a straight & you have the same straight using a card in your hand that is the same straight as the board… ex: Q J 10 9 8 on the board & you have a Q in your hand… who wins the pot?

Comment: one you get a valid five card hand, that is the hand you use, kickers do not count. you are over thinking how to read a hand. keep it simple.

Answer (score -1):

Your Q doesn't matter. Both players have the same hand (a hand consists of the best 5-card combo). You would win if you had a K though. Because a king would give you a higher straight.